# Mysql not found even the Laravel-homestead is installed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, homestead

I am a newbie to both Laravel and PHP. Now I wish to link my Laravel project to Mysql database. I am using the os x 10.10 and I have already installed `homestead` and `vagrant`. But when I input `which mysql` in the command line, it is told that `mysql not found`. 
A mysql database is supposed to be included in the homestead package. But why can't the mysql be found? How can I link my project to mysql db and how can I ensure that I have successfully done that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I guess correctly you are trying to find mysql on your **physical machine**, when it is actually installed on your **virtual machine**. You have to connect to the Homestead via ssh first, in order to do `which mysql`. So in your terminal do:

1. `homestead up`
2. `homestead ssh`
3. `which mysql`

You can read more about Homestead in the documentation [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead). Also you can read [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) to keep up with concept of virtual machine.

To create a new database inside the Homestead you simply have to find you **Homestead.yaml** file (usually path is ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml) and add the name of you database to the databases section:

```
databases:
    - homestead
    - your_new_database_name
```

Then you have to provision the Homestead machine with `homestead provision`. After this the databases will be created and only thing you will have to do is link to it from you projects `.env` file (located in the root of your Laravel project):

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=your_new_database_name
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

This have to do it. The [Laravels documentation regarding database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database) is really great. Usually you can find all you need there. I guess you will need to create some migrations to create the schema for you databases. It is [covered there](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations) too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your guess is right. But I have already used vagrant up to boot up a vm. Do I have to use homestead up?

Comment: You can try to do `homestead ssh` in your terminal then. And I think there is no harm to do `homestead up` again, the worst it can do is to tell you that the machine you trying to run is already running.